# PHP Submit Text Link

Tags: php

How can is submit a this image like a button

```
<a href='home.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin/product_images/$pro_image' width='180' height='180'/></a>


if(isset($_POST['pro_view'])){
            $products_id = $_GET['pro_id'];
            $insert_products = "update products set product_view =  product_view + 1 where product_id = $products_id";
            $insert_pros = mysqli_query($con, $insert_products);
        }
```

Comment: You are not using posting a form, so `$_POST['pro_view']` will not be set. There is no `pro_view` in your code here.

Comment: Yes! how can i do that?

Comment: What the status of this question; resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `img tag` inside `button tag`

```
<button name="button" value="action">
<img src='admin/product_images/image.jpg' width='180' height='180'/> 
</button>
```

or try this code :-

```
<a href='home.php?pro_id=1'>
<img src='admin/product_images/img.png' width='180' height='180'/>
</a>


if(isset($_GET['pro_id'])){
$products_id = $_GET['pro_id'];
$insert_products = "update products set product_view =  product_view + 1 where product_id = $products_id";
$insert_pros = mysqli_query($con, $insert_products);
}
```

Comment: Why not input `image`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image Also that won't work because the PHP variable wont be rendered.

Comment: this `<img src='admin/product_images/$pro_image'` will in fact echo `<img src='admin/product_images/$pro_image'` in HTML source, instead of the intended and for example `<img src='admin/product_images/image.jpg'` just as @chris85 said. Variables do not get parsed in single quotes.